# Can't open page on my application that deploy on Docker

Tags: docker

Windows 10 ,Spring-Boot application
I success run and build my Spring Boot project by Gradle.

In application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8090
```

1. Build by project like this:

   gradlew assemble

As result in folder build create artifact

```
/eshop/java/eshop/build/libs/eshop-0.0.1.jar
```

2. I can run my app like this (in build/lib folder):

   java -jar eshop-0.0.1.jar
3. success open web page on this address:

   http://localhost:8090

Nice.

Now I want to deploy and run my app in Docker.

So here my steps:

1.Create in project folder the next Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD build/libs/eshop-0.0.1.jar eshop-0.0.1.jar
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "eshop-0.0.1.jar"]
```

2. run Docker server
3. open docker console in my project's folder
4. create docker image:

   docker build -f Dockerfile -t eshop .
5. print images list

   docker images

   ```
   $ docker images
   REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
   eshop               latest              d3059d8ce7a0        20 seconds ago      534MB
   <none>              <none>              e25799bbe4e3        23 hours ago        534MB
   openjdk             8                   8c6851b1fc09        6 days ago          488MB
   tomcat              latest              94e31e5297d1        4 weeks ago         507MB
   hello-world         latest              fce289e99eb9        13 months ago       1.84kB
   ```
6. run docker container from my image on port 8090

   docker run eshop -p 8090:8090

   ```
   [INFO ] 2020-01-29 17:05:24.265 [main] ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
   [INFO ] 2020-01-29 17:05:24.878 [main] WelcomePageHandlerMapping - Adding welcome page template: index
   [INFO ] 2020-01-29 17:05:26.209 [main] EndpointLinksResolver - Exposing 5 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
   [INFO ] 2020-01-29 17:05:26.480 [main] Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
   [INFO ] 2020-01-29 17:05:26.601 [main] TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''
   [INFO ] 2020-01-29 17:05:26.610 [main] Main - Started Main in 34.679 seconds (JVM running for 42.95)
   ```
7. print all containers

   $ docker ps
   CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
   bf2833e14739        eshop               "java -jar eshop-0.0…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   8085/tcp            flamboyant_brown
8. print ip address on my container

   $ docker inspect bf2833e14739 | grep "IPAddress"
                   "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
                   "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
       "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
9. Now I try to open my app on address  `http://172.17.0.2:8090/`  but it not open.
   Also try on `http://172.17.0.2:8085/` but it's not open

why?

Comment: your application runs on 8090 and your exposing 8085!

Comment: Docker-specific options like `-p` need to come _before_ the image name.  The `docker inspect` IP address is useless except on one very specific Docker host configuration and I’d recommend never looking it up.

Comment: @Elgayed but I use this to expose my app: docker run eshop -p 8090:8090. It must be on port 8090  ?

Comment: @DavidMaze I try this docker run -p 8090:8090 eshop, but it also not help.

Comment: I change in application.yml to EXPOSE 8090 , but it also not help

Answer (score 0):

I found solution :

1. print ip

   docker-machine ip default

I get `192.168.99.100`

2. run container

   docker run -p 8090:8090 eshop
3. And open page on the next address:

   http://192.168.99.100:8090/

And now it's open success